# Swift compile errors FileBrowser, swift 2.3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, cocoapods

I am trying to debug my beta, which worked really fine before iOS 10, Swift 3. and I don't see the end.

I cannot build it. My app is in Swift 2.3 (Xcode 8)
I have an error with the Library FileBrowser version 0.1.4

I add on Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
end
```

But I am still having a compile error with the library FileBrowser
error:

> Type of previewItemURL' has different optionality than required by protocol 'QLPreviewItem' PreviewManager.swift

Comment: Have you tried updating your pods? pod update

Comment: yes of course but the issue is that there are some libraries with curent version only working with swift 3, and i had to change some branches that support swift 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Well the library FileBrowser doesn't support Swift 2.3 only swift 3.
 Two choices:
- Change library for browsing file
- Switch all the project to swift 3